# Asyncio : how to run one task in another one concurrently?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

I have two functions, both are async and they run outside a function thanks to asyncio
However, the second function is inside the first one, and it's blocking the execution of the first :
*(note that this needs to be compatible with most used Python versions, from 3.8 to latest one)*

```py
async def func_2():
  # basically does a request to a website and returns the status code

async def func_1():
  tab = ["el0", "el1", ..., "el10"]  
  for i in range(len(tab)):
    sys.stdout.write("\r[∆] Progress: " + tab[i % len(tab)])
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if i == 1:
      result = await func_2()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.4)
  return result

while True: 
  func = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  func_coroutine = func_1()
  result = anim.run_until_complete(func_coroutine)
  if result == 200:
    print("Up")
  else:
    print("Down")
```

The `func_1()` is just here  to make the user wait, but the `func_2()` does the real job, and takes way more time than 0.4 seconds

So my question is : It is possible to make the `func_1()` continuing to run (and show stuff to the user) while the `func_2()` is running ?

Comment: Is there a strong use case for why this needs to use `async`? This looks more like a case where threading would be a better fit (e.g.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-threadpoolexecutor-in-python-3)

Comment: in such case, how to use Threading ?  it's not mandatory to use async, however I'm more used to it and the program needs to be fast, I'm a bit afraid that Threads would make it heavier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, convert `func_2` into a task.  Then loop inside `func_1` until `func_2` is finished.  The two tasks will play together, giving an appearance of concurrency.

I replaced your `func_2` with a simple `asyncio.sleep`.  I used the print function for the status messages instead of `stdout.write`.  I print the final result, showing that the data from `func_2` is accessible by the task's `result()` method.

I realize that your application will do something useful, so this little script is just an example framework.

Tested with Python 3.10 on Win10.

```
import asyncio

async def func_2():
    await asyncio.sleep(2.0)
    return 42

async def func_1():
    my_task = asyncio.create_task(func_2())
    i = 0
    while not my_task.done():
        print(f"\rProgress: el{i}", end='')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.4)
        i += 1
    return my_task.result()

print('\nDone...', asyncio.run(func_1()))
```

Comment: I applied your method, and the concept of tasks is really interesting 
However the `func_1()` is a kind of progressbar and can't be cut when my_task is done. So I added something to complete it when the task is done, but the main problem is still there: the func_1 still waits than the func_2 is completed before continuing...

Comment: You said that you wanted func_2 to wait "while func_1 is running".  That's exactly what my script does.  I don't know what you mean by the "the func_1 still waits than the func_2 is completed." Did you use the wrong word in there somewhere?  If you want func_1 to keep running after func_2 is completed, just change `while not my_task.done()` to `while True`.  But in that case you have to find some other way of exiting the while loop.  I probably don't understand your real problem, sorry.

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't say that the concept of a task is "really interesting."  It's absolutely central to the whole purpose of asyncio, which is to allow one task to run while other tasks wait for something.  In your script you have only one task, so your program might as well not use asyncio at all.  When you await func_2(), func_1 stops at that point and doesn't continue until func_2 returns.  That's just like a regular subroutine call in a sync program.  You're not getting any benefit from asyncio.

Comment: okay so to put it in a nutshell : i want the `func_1()` to run and do its job *at the same time* that `func_2()` do its thing

Comment: Let me show you : https://telegra.ph/file/d7c776063ad77f5f3574c.gif  
The `func_1()` makes the progressbar, and it works. But at the beginning (on 0%) it calls `func_2()` and that one is blocking `func_1()` (no edit of the progressbar)
and when `func_2()` is done, then the progressbar edits again.  
what I want is to run both of them at the same time, without one blocking the other

Comment: Again I will say that my little script runs func_1 and func_2 at the same time, and neither one blocks the other.  I think I understand what you want but I don't understand why you don't already have it.  Perhaps you can tell me more about func_2.  Does it make a blocking I/O call?  Blocking calls are not compatible with asyncio.  Does it contain await expressions that yield control periodically back to the event loop?  Await expressions are necessary to let multiple tasks cooperate.

Comment: the only thing "long" it does is calling `urllib.request.urlopen()`. Tho idk if it's blocking

Comment: From the docs for urlopen: `urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)`.  A few paragraphs down it says: "The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used). This actually only works for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP connections."  So yes, it's definitely blocking.

Comment: You need to use threads to get around the blocking call.  If you're running python3.10 or later, see the function to_thread in asyncio.  But perhaps you don't want asyncio at all; unless the script requires asyncio for some other reason, the thread module would provide all the functionality you need.